# Cakephp dynamic select field with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I work with cakephp 3 and i need to create dynamic select input. When i select first, second is auto populated.
I found script for cakephp 2 and i'm trying to implement it in cake3.

Here is my view.ctp code:

```
 <?= $this->Form->select('country_id' ,$optionsCountry, ['id' => 'country_id']); ?>
 <?= $this->Form->select('Base', $optionsBase); ?>
```

Here is ajax code.

```
$this->Js->get('#country_id')->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller' => 'countries',
        'action' => 'get_by_country',
            ), array(
        'update' => '#city_id',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'Post',
        'dataExpression' => true,
        'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => true,
            'inline' => true
        ))
    ))
);
```

And when i load page i get eror:

```
Error: Call to a member function event() on a non-object
```

with pointer to line where is:
`$this->Js->get('#country_id')->event('change', $this->Js->request(array(`

In my view source i see one input field with id="country_id"
i have no idea what else could i try,

any idea how to realize dinamic select field or what could be wrong here?
tnx

Comment: You can do it in a simple way

Comment: for example, please?

Comment: listen fire an onchange event in your first select field , fire an ajax call , get all the required data using ajax call and load it to the second select box .simple .  @marko_b123

Comment: There is no Js helper in CakePHP 3, so you can't just use the v2 solution.